# Sumas duplicadas en consulta Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Cordial saludo,

Tengo las siguientes tablas en Mysql:

```
mysql> SELECT ID_PROD,DESCRIP FROM PRODUCTOS;
+---------+------------------+
| ID_PROD | DESCRIP          |
+---------+------------------+
| 001     | POKER            |
| 002     | AGUILA           |
| 003     | GASEOSA          |
| 004     | VIEJO DE CALDAS  |
| 005     | VIEJO DE CALDAS  |
| 006     | BLANCO DEL VALLE |
+---------+------------------+

mysql> SELECT ID_PROD,VR_PUBLI FROM PROD_PREC;
+---------+----------+
| ID_PROD | VR_PUBLI |
+---------+----------+
| 001     |     8000 |
| 002     |     8000 |
| 003     |     3500 |
| 004     |   110000 |
| 005     |    60000 |
| 006     |    50000 |
+---------+----------+

mysql> SELECT FECHA,PRODU,UNDS FROM BARRA;
+--------+-------+------+
| FECHA  | PRODU | UNDS |
+--------+-------+------+
| 191028 | 002   |    2 |
| 191028 | 005   |    5 |
| 191028 | 002   |    1 |
+--------+-------+------+

mysql> SELECT FECHA,ID_PROD,E_UNDS,S_UNDS FROM INVENTARIO;
+---------------------+---------+--------+--------+
| FECHA               | ID_PROD | E_UNDS | S_UNDS |
+---------------------+---------+--------+--------+
| 2019-10-28 00:00:00 | 001     |     24 |      0 |
| 2019-10-28 00:00:00 | 002     |      4 |      0 |
| 2019-10-31 00:00:00 | 002     |      0 |      2 |
+---------------------+---------+--------+--------+
```

Pero al realizar esta consulta:

```
SELECT P.ID_PROD,P.DESCRIP,V.VR_PUBLI,IFNULL(SUM(B.UNDS),0) 
BARRA_UNDS,IFNULL(SUM(I.E_UNDS),0) ENTRA_UNDS_INV,IFNULL(SUM(I.S_UNDS),0) 
SALE_UNDS_INV
FROM PRODUCTOS P 
join PROD_PREC V ON P.ID_PROD = V.ID_PROD 
LEFT join BARRA B ON P.ID_PROD = B.PRODU 
LEFT JOIN INVENTARIO I ON P.ID_PROD = I.ID_PROD
GROUP BY P.ID_PROD
```

Obtengo esto:

```
+---------+------------------+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+
| ID_PROD | DESCRIP          | VR_PUBLI | BARRA_UNDS | ENTRA_UNDS_INV | SALE_UNDS_INV |
+---------+------------------+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+
| 001     | POKER            |     8000 |          0 |             24 |             0 |
| 002     | AGUILA           |     8000 |          6 |              8 |             4 |
| 003     | GASEOSA          |     3500 |          0 |              0 |             0 |
| 004     | VIEJO DE CALDAS  |   110000 |          0 |              0 |             0 |
| 005     | VIEJO DE CALDAS  |    60000 |          5 |              0 |             0 |
| 006     | BLANCO DEL VALLE |    50000 |          0 |              0 |             0 |
+---------+------------------+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+
```

y deberia ser esto:

```
+---------+------------------+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+
| ID_PROD | DESCRIP          | VR_PUBLI | BARRA_UNDS | ENTRA_UNDS_INV | SALE_UNDS_INV |
+---------+------------------+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+
| 001     | POKER            |     8000 |          0 |             24 |             0 |
| 002     | AGUILA           |     8000 |          3 |              4 |             2 |
| 003     | GASEOSA          |     3500 |          0 |              0 |             0 |
| 004     | VIEJO DE CALDAS  |   110000 |          0 |              0 |             0 |
| 005     | VIEJO DE CALDAS  |    60000 |          5 |              0 |             0 |
| 006     | BLANCO DEL VALLE |    50000 |          0 |              0 |             0 |
+---------+------------------+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Al tener mas de un registro con igual registro en la tabla BAR columna PRODU en este caso es 002 se duplica la suma, lo mismo sucede con la tabla INVENTARIO columna ID_PROD igual que en BARRA es 002, también duplica la suma. He tratado con GROUP BY pero da igual resultado.

No se realmente en la consulta SQL que debo hacer para que tanto en BARRA como en INVENTARIO no se duplique la suma cuando aparezcan dos o mas registros (que como coincidencia es 002).

Comment: ¿Se solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 3):

No tengo como probar en estos momentos, pero la solución más sencilla es hacer una sumatoria antes de unir las tablas para tener solo una fila por producto.

```
SELECT P.ID_PROD,P.DESCRIP,V.VR_PUBLI,IFNULL(SUM(B.UNDS),0) 
BARRA_UNDS,IFNULL(SUM(I.E_UNDS),0) ENTRA_UNDS_INV,IFNULL(SUM(I.S_UNDS),0) 
SALE_UNDS_INV
FROM PRODUCTOS P 
join PROD_PREC V ON P.ID_PROD = V.ID_PROD 
LEFT join (SELECT PRODU, SUM(UNDS) AS UNDS FROM BARRA GROUP BY PRODU)B ON P.ID_PROD = B.PRODU 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID_PROD, SUM(E_UNDS) AS E_UNDS, SUM(S_UNDS) AS S_UNDS FROM INVENTARIO GROUP BY ID_PROD) I ON P.ID_PROD = I.ID_PROD
GROUP BY P.ID_PROD
```

Comment: Los `SUM` y el `GROUP BY` en la consulta principal estarían sobrando ya que los datos en cuestión ya vienen sumandos

Comment: No forzosamente, pero tienes razón. Tengo la costumbre de mantenerlos porque hay veces en que puede requerirse así, aunque no sea el caso aquí.

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono

Answer (score 2):

Un solución simple sería obtener la suman de los `BARRA_UNDS` utilizando subconsultas

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT
    P.ID_PROD,
    P.DESCRIP,
    V.VR_PUBLI,
    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(B.UNDS),0)
      FROM BARRA B 
       WHERE B.PRODU = P.ID_PROD) AS BARRA_UNDS,
    IFNULL(SUM(I.E_UNDS),0) AS ENTRA_UNDS_INV,
    IFNULL(SUM(I.S_UNDS),0) AS SALE_UNDS_INV
  FROM PRODUCTOS P 
    LEFT JOIN PROD_PREC V
      ON V.ID_PROD = P.ID_PROD  
    LEFT JOIN INVENTARIO I
      ON I.ID_PROD = P.ID_PROD
  GROUP BY P.ID_PROD
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte me ha sido de ayuda en comprender mas cosas de SQL